# what happen with my componentDidUpdate in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, frontend, lifecycle

> this is file app.js

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoLists: [],
      inputValue: "",
      currentName: "",
      todoSearch: "",
      idUpdate: "",
      loader: true
    };
  }
 componentDidUpdate(){
    this.setState({
      loader: true
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://5ec912d99ccbaf0016aa8b6f.mockapi.io/todoLists")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          loader: false,
          todoLists: res.data
        });
      });
  }
...
```

> i added componentDidUpdate in my App but it message :  Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 3):

componentDidUpdate Call every time when set state happen so, you have to remove setState in didUpdate or call based on condition  like this ..

```
componentDidupdate(){
 //check this is called every time when render executed .
 console.log('did update');
  if(some condition){
   this.setState({});
 }
}
```

Comment: @Khoa Võ Đức if this does ans your que than please do it as marked so can close this que .

Answer (score 0):

So, you're updating something in componentDidUpdate that is in the state, and updating the state triggers this, so it's in an infinite loop, could you explain what you're trying to do I could give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this way to avoid maximum loop executions.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todoLists: [],
      loader: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loader: true });
    axios
      .get("https://5ec912d99ccbaf0016aa8b6f.mockapi.io/todoLists")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          loader: false,
          todoLists: res.data
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { loader } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loader
          ? "Loading"
          : this.state.todoLists.map(res => {
              return (
                <ul key={res.id}>
                  <li>{res.id}</li>
                  <li>{res.name}</li>
                </ul>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```